# jquery twitter plugin capable of using twitter lists API?

Tags: jquery, api, twitter

What is the best jquery twitter plugin capable of using the twitter lists API?

I want to display a list of the latest tweets using jquery given the name of the twitter list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define best. As far as I can see [Tweet!](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) supports lists. Why not give it a try?

Comment: best = something that works. Tweet! looks like it will do. Thanks! I had tried two other plugins but not Tweet!